# Recognizing 1 class propriets to 2 class that implements action Listener interface

Tags: java, swing

For first excuse me for my bad English or explaination:.
Before asking I searched online but everything I found haven't helped me.

So I have 2 classes :
1- extends JFRAME  and thats my window layout there I have all propriets .
2- implement action Listener to handle button click event 
First the problem was : how can I show my main class propriets to the 2 class?

And I did this :

```
public class MyWindow extends JFrame{

// Here I put the properties I needed 

  private JTextField txt.....;
  .........
  .....

 p

    ublic MyWindow (){
      init();
      }
      public void init(){
      // Here I have  my layout 
      // And I have button confirm so I did this to 
      //Manage the event 
      JButton confirm= new JButton("Confirm");
      confirm.addActionEventLister(MyListner(this));

    //  passed  the class that implements the method 
    //action performed ...
      }
```

2- class that manage the event

```
public class MyListner implements ActionListener{
  // I made properties called frame 
 private frame ;

  public MyListner (MyWindow frame){
       frame = frame ; //
   } 

 public void actionPerformed ( ActionListener e ) {
  // Here when I use frame.Propriets o methods are 
 // Null 
 String a;
a = frame.getTxTSurname().getText(); 
.....
...
// I don't know why I got nullPointerException 
// Also in debug frame is null and all propriets
```

// Are null . 
     }

}

So the problems is why frame is null and why all the properties I want to modify are null ? I am getting null pointer exception

Comment: Please write proper Java code. The `frame = frame ;` is one of the problems you have.

Comment: thanks very much  for the answer , but can you tell me what's wrong with that ? I'm new to java so it would help me a lot ..

Comment: That statement assign variable to itself and wont initialize `private frame ;`. Try `this.frame = frame;`.

Comment: My bad haven't noticed that :) ,  that was the problem , my god